# How to start a module without calling it in the app.js

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I have created an npm package, this module is declared in the app.js. Inside this module I declare some bundles with moogBundle

```
moogBundle = {
  modules: ['add-car-widgets','helpers'],
  directory: 'lib/modules'
}
```

I'm trying to get them initialized inside this package and not inside the app.js. I have tried to recreate the initiation of the apostrophe modules (node_modules/apostrophe/index.js) as follows

```
construct: function(self,options) {
  var defaults = require('./defaults.js');
  _.merge(self.apos.options.modules, defaults.modules);

  _.each(self.apos.options.modules, function(options, name) {
      self.apos.synth.define(name, options);

  });
```

The file defaults :

```
module.exports = {
  modules: {

   'add-car-widgets':{},
   'helpers':{},
 }
};
```

In the content of the attribute self.apos.options the modules which I want to declare are added, however, in the view they are not initialized:

```
'add-car-widgets':
    { __meta:
        { dirname:
            '/mnt/c/Users/rafael.soria/Desktop/sandbox/lib/modules/add-car-widgets',
        filename:
            '/mnt/c/Users/rafael.soria/Desktop/sandbox/lib/modules/add-car-widgets/index.js' } },

helpers:
    { __meta:
        { dirname:
            '/mnt/c/Users/rafael.soria/Desktop/sandbox/lib/modules/helpers',
        filename:
            '/mnt/c/Users/rafael.soria/Desktop/sandbox/lib/modules/helpers/index.js' } } }
```

I wanted to know if I'm on the right track, or if it's possible to do what I'm doing.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after days of trying to find the solution, I found it. I still needed to create the declared object. If anyone in the future has the same doubt would create it the following way:

```
self.apos.synth.create(name-module, { apos: self.apos })
```

Comment: Glad you found a workaround. This feature doesn't officially exist at this time. It would make sense for us to look into whether there's a good way to support it with less work and ensure your module is initialized at the normal time and without any surprises or bc breaks later. Feel free to open a github issue.